# How to overwrite custom component css in angular 8

Tags: css, typescript, angular7, angular8

I tried to overwrite the css of a custom component selector but it is not working. I have tried `:ng-deep` without success. How do I find a solution for this?

app.component.html:

```
<mycustommcomp></mycustommcomp>
```

app.component.css:

```
::ng-deep mycustommcomp{ 
margin:2px;
overflow:unset !important; 
}
```

mycustomcomp.component.css:

```
mycustommcomp{ 
margin:8px;
overflow:hidden !important; 
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsdzqs?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as style cannot be applied to component tags. One way to make it works is to wrap the content inside mycustommcomp with a container (such as div).

mycustommcomp.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
   <!--Content here-->
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
::ng-deep .container{ 
   margin:2px;
   overflow:unset !important; 
}
```

mycustomcomp.component.css:

```
.container{ 
   margin:8px;
   overflow:hidden !important; 
}
```

Nevertheless please avoid doing this as ::ng-deep is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

Comment: Do not use class.i want to overwrite the selector mycustommcomp css